# Check object is equal to generic type

Tags: c#, .net, typeof, gettype, generic-type-argument

I have a method that does some type conversion. I don't want to go through the whole process if the type is equal to the generic types passed. Here's a snippet.

```
    public static T ConvertTo<T>(this object @this)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == @this.GetType())
            return (T)@this;
    }
```

I'm checking is the object @this is already of type T which seems to work, but is this the best way of doing this?

Comment: Any reason you want to use the *exact* type rather than `is`?

Comment: No Jon but being a 'dotnetnoob' I could get the 'is' syntax to work for me.

Comment: One other thing to check: do you need this to work for value types as well as reference types? If not, a `where T : class` constraint may make life simpler.

Comment: It needs to work for int (+ other numeric variants) + bool/guid/string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IsInstaceOfType` method and `is` to check the type.

```
public static T ConvertTo<T>(this object @this)
{
    if (@this is T)
       return (T)@this;
    else
       return default(T);
}
```

Comment: why not just say `@this is T` instead of `typeof(T).IsInstanceOfType(@this)`.

Comment: Something else must be wrong. `@this is T` is a perfectly valid expression. (I just tested it to make sure I'm not smoking something).

Answer (score 0):

This might also work

```
public static T ConvertTo<T>(this object @this)
{
    return (T)System.Convert.ChangeType(@this, typeof(T));
}
```